DetectDragGesture Vertical Drag Issue in LazyColumn
val users = state.data.toMutableStateList()
                val dragAndDropListState = rememberDragAndDropListState(lazyListState) { from, to ->
                    users.move(from, to)
                }
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            val initialTouchPosition = mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)

                            detectDragGestures(

                                onDrag = { change, offset ->
                                    change.consume()
                                    dragAndDropListState.onDrag(offset)

                               if (overscrollJob?.isActive == true) return@detectDragGestures

                                    dragAndDropListState
                                        .checkOverscroll()
                                        .takeIf { it != 0f }
                                        ?.let {
                                            overscrollJob = coroutineScope.launch {
                                                dragAndDropListState.lazyListState.scrollBy(it)
                                            }
                                        } ?: kotlin.run { overscrollJob?.cancel() }

                                },
                                onDragStart = { offset ->
                                    if (offset.getDistance() > 10.dp.toPx()) {
                                        initialTouchPosition.value = offset
                                        dragAndDropListState.onDragStart(offset)
                                    }
                                },
                                onDragEnd = { dragAndDropListState.onDragInterrupted() },
                                onDragCancel = { dragAndDropListState.onDragInterrupted() },

                                )
                        }, state = dragAndDropListState.lazyListState
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(users) { index, user ->
                        ItemCard(userEntityUi = user, modifier = Modifier.composed {
                            val offsetOrNull = dragAndDropListState.elementDisplacement.takeIf {
                                index == dragAndDropListState.currentIndexOfDraggedItem
                            }
                            Modifier.graphicsLayer {
                                translationY = offsetOrNull ?: 0f
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }



I'm implementing detectDragGestures in a Jetpack Compose LazyColumn to allow vertical dragging. However, I've noticed an issue where dragging vertically doesn't work unless I first make a small horizontal drag gesture. After that, vertical dragging starts working as expected.
How can I fix this issue to ensure vertical dragging works immediately without requiring any horizontal movement?

@thracian waiting for the help from your side

You can use Modifier.draggable( startDragImmediately = true) to start dragging without awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation check which is check for passing threshold to start dragging.
@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyColumnScroll() {

    Column {

        var initialTouchPosition by remember {
            mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
        }

        val draggableState = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
            initialTouchPosition = initialTouchPosition.plus(Offset(0f, delta))
        }

        Text("Position: $initialTouchPosition")
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .draggable(
                    state = draggableState,
                    startDragImmediately = true,
                    onDragStarted = {
                        initialTouchPosition = it
                    },

                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical
                )

        ) {
            items(100) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Row: $it", fontSize = 22.sp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I've done something like this before, you can check out my implementation of DragDropState:
@Composable
fun rememberDragDropState(
    lazyListState: LazyListState,
    key1: Any? = null,
    key2: Any? = null,
    onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit
): DragDropState {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val state = remember(lazyListState, key1, key2) {
        DragDropState(state = lazyListState, onMove = onMove, scope = scope)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(state) {
        while (true) {
            val diff = state.scrollChannel.receive()
            lazyListState.scrollBy(diff)
        }
    }
    return state
}

class DragDropState internal constructor(
    private val state: LazyListState,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit
) {
    var draggingItemIndex by mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)
        private set

    internal val scrollChannel = Channel<Float>()

    private var draggingItemDraggedDelta by mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
    private var draggingItemInitialOffset by mutableIntStateOf(0)
    internal val draggingItemOffset: Float
        get() =
            draggingItemLayoutInfo?.let { item ->
                draggingItemInitialOffset + draggingItemDraggedDelta - item.offset
            } ?: 0f

    private val draggingItemLayoutInfo: LazyListItemInfo?
        get() = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == draggingItemIndex }

    internal var previousIndexOfDraggedItem by mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)
        private set

    internal var previousItemOffset = Animatable(0f)
        private set

    internal fun onDragStart(offset: Offset) {
        state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { item -> offset.y.toInt() in item.offset..(item.offset + item.size) }
            ?.also {
                draggingItemIndex = it.index
                draggingItemInitialOffset = it.offset
            }
    }

    internal fun onDragInterrupted() {
        if (draggingItemIndex != null) {
            previousIndexOfDraggedItem = draggingItemIndex
            val startOffset = draggingItemOffset
            scope.launch {
                previousItemOffset.snapTo(startOffset)
                previousItemOffset.animateTo(
                    0f,
                    spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow, visibilityThreshold = 1f)
                )
                previousIndexOfDraggedItem = null
            }
        }
        draggingItemDraggedDelta = 0f
        draggingItemIndex = null
        draggingItemInitialOffset = 0
    }

    internal fun onDrag(offset: Offset) {
        draggingItemDraggedDelta += offset.y

        val draggingItem = draggingItemLayoutInfo ?: return
        val startOffset = draggingItem.offset + draggingItemOffset
        val endOffset = startOffset + draggingItem.size
        val middleOffset = startOffset + (endOffset - startOffset) / 2f

        val targetItem =
            state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.find { item ->
                middleOffset.toInt() in item.offset..item.offsetEnd &&
                        draggingItem.index != item.index
            }
        if (targetItem != null) {
            if (
                draggingItem.index == state.firstVisibleItemIndex ||
                targetItem.index == state.firstVisibleItemIndex
            ) {
                state.requestScrollToItem(
                    state.firstVisibleItemIndex,
                    state.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
                )
            }
            onMove.invoke(draggingItem.index, targetItem.index)
            draggingItemIndex = targetItem.index
        } else {
            val overscroll =
                when {
                    draggingItemDraggedDelta > 0 ->
                        (endOffset - state.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset).coerceAtLeast(0f)

                    draggingItemDraggedDelta < 0 ->
                        (startOffset - state.layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset).coerceAtMost(0f)

                    else -> 0f
                }
            if (overscroll != 0f) {
                scrollChannel.trySend(overscroll)
            }
        }
    }

    private val LazyListItemInfo.offsetEnd: Int
        get() = this.offset + this.size
}

fun Modifier.dragContainer(dragDropState: DragDropState): Modifier {
    return pointerInput(dragDropState) {
        detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
            onDrag = { change, offset ->
                change.consume()
                dragDropState.onDrag(offset = offset)
            },
            onDragStart = { offset -> dragDropState.onDragStart(offset) },
            onDragEnd = { dragDropState.onDragInterrupted() },
            onDragCancel = { dragDropState.onDragInterrupted() }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun LazyItemScope.DraggableItem(
    dragDropState: DragDropState,
    index: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable (isDragging: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val dragging = index == dragDropState.draggingItemIndex
    val draggingModifier =
        if (dragging) {
            Modifier
                .zIndex(1f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationY = dragDropState.draggingItemOffset
                }
        } else if (index == dragDropState.previousIndexOfDraggedItem) {
            Modifier
                .zIndex(1f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationY = dragDropState.previousItemOffset.value
                }
        } else {
            Modifier.animateItem()
        }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.then(draggingModifier),
        content = { content(dragging) }
    )
}

Usage example:
val items = remember { List(10) { it }.toMutableStateList() }
val state = rememberLazyListState()
val dragDropState = rememberDragDropState(state) { from, to ->
    val temp = items[from]
    items[from] = items[to]
    items[to] = temp
}

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.dragContainer(dragDropState),
    state = state
) {
    itemsIndexed(
        items = items,
        key = { index, item -> item }
    ) { index, item ->
        DraggableItem(
            dragDropState = dragDropState,
            index = index
        ) { isDragging ->
            ListItem(
                headlineContent = {
                    Text("Item: $item")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


Thank for Your response but your code also working correctly with Long Press but i want to implement immediate drag and drop with no delay and move directly vertical orientation.
